# Expected value of $\frac{1}{x}$

Tags: probability, random-variables

Given $X \sim G(\frac{3}{8})$ (and so, $E(X) = \frac{8}{3}$, what is $E(\frac{1}{X})$? ($X$ can get values $1,2,...$

I tried:

> $E(\frac{1}{X}) = \Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty} {g(x_k)P(X=k)} = \Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty} {\frac{1}{n}(\frac{5}{8})^{n-1} \frac{3}{8}}$ but it doesn't exist..

Comment: doesn't that mean it doesn't exist?

Comment: Professor answer: $\frac{3}{5} ln(\frac{2}{3})$, that's why I asked here, and he wouldn't tell me why "Figure it out yourself"

Comment: But $\ln(2/3)$ is negative!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the Taylor series of $-\log(1-x)$ is 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k}=x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots$$
Therefore your expression becomes
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1k\left(\frac58\right)^{k-1}\frac38&=\frac38\cdot\frac85\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1k\left(\frac58\right)^k \\
&=\frac35\cdot\left(-\log\left(1-\frac58\right)\right) \\
&=\frac35\log\left(\frac83\right)
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$$\ln(1-x)= -\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n}$$

Therefore

$$-\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n-1}}{n}.$$